# Creating a Gemfile with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, thinking-sphinx

I have a rails 2.3.8 app. I just installed RVM, and apparently things are working ok (I created a very simple rails project to check that rails and mysql were running ok).

I am now trying to create a Gemfile... but am facing a problem with Thinking-Sphinx. Here is the current version of my Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems
source "http://rubygems.org"
source :rubyforge
source "http://gems.rubyforge.org"
source :gemcutter
source "http://gemcutter.org"

gem 'SystemTimer', :platforms => :ruby_18
gem "rails", "2.3.5"
# make sure to run "bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config" in terminal before running "bundle install" as per documentation in http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html
gem "mysql"

gem "tlsmail"
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 2.3.11'

gem "chronic"
gem "nokogiri"

gem "sphinx", '0.9.10.2122'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '< 2.0.0', :require => 'thinking_sphinx'
gem 'ts-delayed-delta', :require => 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta'

gem "mini_magick"
gem "faker"
gem "populator"

gem "rspec"
gem "geokit"
gem "geokit-rails"
```

And my Rakefile is:

```
require 'thread'
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'

require 'tasks/rails'
require 'thinking_sphinx/tasks'
require 'thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta/tasks'

begin
  gem 'delayed_job', '~>2.0.3'
  require 'delayed/tasks'
rescue LoadError
  STDERR.puts "Run `rake gems:install` to install delayed_job"
end
```

When I run

> rake ts:config

I get the following error message:

```
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)

Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
  * bin_path
  * searchd_binary_name
  * indexer_binary_name


For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html          

Generating Configuration to /Users/alex/Sites/myproject/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta

Tasks: TOP => ts:config => thinking_sphinx:configure
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've been trying different things for a couple hours but can't find how to solve the problem... would love some help!

Comment: What is the contents of your `Gemfile.lock` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `bundle exec rake ts:config`

This will use the version you specified in your Gemfile.

Comment: Ouch!!! It turns out I forgot to install Sphinx on my new machine!... Now the message I get is: "uninitialized constant ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174/gems/thinking-sphinx-1.4.3/lib/thinking_sphinx/deltas.rb:11:in `parse'".

Comment: Well, you know what to do then! :)

Comment: For some reason it seems I have to leave "config.gem 'ts-delayed-delta',:lib..." in my environment.rb file. Is it normal?

Answer (score -9):

My advice is to not use RVM. It is a good idea, but poorly implemented. If you need multiple ruby versions like me it is far less of a hassle to just create aliases for each one.

RVM causes issues from time to time, using aliases never does.

Comment: How is this not a useful answer? It solves his issue and won't have anything like it happen in the future.